# MIDI or WAV file to an array of frequencies and duration

Tags: c#, audio, signal-processing

Is there any script/software/algorithm which allows to convert a MIDI (or WAV) file to a list of `<frequency, duration>` so that we can replay an 'image' of this sound file, for example, through the `System.Console.Beep(frequency, duration)` function in C#?

Comment: You've asked two monstrously different questions there. MIDI and WAV are totally different, not just in the format but also in the entire concept of the way they store audio. MIDI stores audio as a series of notes, and therefore it is trivial to extract the frequency and duration pairs (I don't know of any specific software for doing this; I have written my own to do just that in a very hacky way). WAV is digital samples so you would need frequency analysis software to get the note data out. That's possible, but not 100% accurate and a completely different kettle of fish. So which do you want?

Comment: At least, how to do for the MIDI file (but tell me also the principles  for the WAV as I'm curious, I read somewhere that FFT is insufficient)

Comment: It's really a fascinating idea.  Probably you take the WAV file, convert to the frequency domain (eg FFT) and then apply a psycoacoustic model to pick the single "beep" that a human would hear.  Sort of the audio equivalent of a photoshop "impressionist" filter...

Comment: Ask this as two completely different questions and you might get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the MIDI, WAV or other sound file to raw audio samples. Then for successive blocks of samples (typically overlapping each block by 50%), apply a window function (e.g. Hanning), then an FFT, then take the magnitude of the FFT output bins, then for audio you would usually take 20*log10 of this magnitude to get a dB value.

Comment: +1, This is fine for WAV, but don't bother with this method for MIDI.  If you have something in MIDI, then don't synthesize it and read it back.

Comment: @Brad: it depends whether you just want note information (which of course you can get directly from the MIDI data) or whether you want the complete audio spectrum - the OP's question is pretty vague as to what kind of "image" he wants.

Comment: Note that this FFT method will give the approximate spectral frequencies in the sound, not the musical note or pitch frequencies in music.  The durations will also be quantized to the time steps of the FFT windows, which may or may not be an accurate measure of the length of any actual note or tone burst.

Answer (score 2):

For MIDI, you must either parse the file yourself (which I have done, and I recommend the following two references: [one](http://253.ccarh.org/handout/smf/) and [two](http://www.srm.com/qtma/davidsmidispec.html)), or get a MIDI toolkit. I don't know of any for .NET but [here is a Google search](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=midi+file+library&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=kEE&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=midi+file+library+.net&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=9de2688f68b31204).

Once you get that, it should be fairly easy. Read in the MIDI file using the toolkit, and this will give you a set of *tracks*. Each track contains a sequence of *events*, each with a timestamp relative to the previous event. An event can be "note on", "note off", or one of hundreds of other events you probably don't care about and can ignore for this exercise. Just look for the "note on" and "note off" events. Usually, each note is a "note on" (with a certain pitch and velocity, which is volume) followed by a "note off" some time later (with the same pitch, and a velocity of 0).

So armed with this information, you can construct a table of notes with a quadruple (start time, duration, pitch, velocity), where start time is the time of the "note on" event, duration is the time difference between "note on" and "note off", and pitch/velocity is the pitch/velocity of the "note on". You can convert the pitch to frequency using [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI_Tuning_Standard).

As for WAV/MP3/AAC/OGG, all of those have the same technique which is what Paul suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Paul R's explanation is fine for WAV.

For MIDI, you're going to have to pick a track and read in the MIDI data.  How you decide which track is up to you, but you can really only pick one, since you only get one "note" at a time out of the PC speaker, using your method.

C# MIDI Tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MIDIToolkit.aspx

Once you have read up on that, you should know how to read a MIDI file in.  From there, you can translate that to frequencies and durations.  The duration depends on tempo and the number of ticks that a note lasts, and the pitch will depend on a note number and its corresponding frequency according to [equal temperament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament#Calculating_absolute_frequencies).  (If you wanted to get really crazy, you could even handle alternate tunings, but I wouldn't worry about it for now.)

Also, I believe [NAudio has some MIDI classes for reading files](http://naudio.codeplex.com/), but they may not be complete.

While we're getting crazy... if you could thread it effectively (this would be near impossible I'd imagine, but...), for WAV playback, you could use [PWM to drive the PC speaker and emulate PCM audio playback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_speaker#Pulse-width_modulation).  I remember some old [DOS games from Necrobones](http://necrobones.com/) used to do this, and there was a driver for Windows 3.1 that worked great on my 33MHz laptop for the usual clicks and dings.  Although this method from a managed framework (or even within Windows without a realtime priority) might be very difficult.